# Deletion from B tree

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, b-tree

I have question in my homework its about b-tree deletion with minimum branching factor t=2.

```
                 [P]
               /      \
              /        \
             /          \
            /            \
           /              \     
        [G][L]            [W]
       /  |   \          /   \
      /   |    \        /     \
     /    |     \      /       \
   BD     J      N     R        Y
 / | \   / \    / \   / \      / \
A  C  F  I K    M  O  Q  ST   X   Z
```

Now after deleting Y from the above tree i get the final tree..

```
                 [P]
               /      \
              /        \
             /          \
            /            \
           /              \     
        [G][L]            [W]
       /  |   \          /   \
      /   |    \        /     \
     /    |     \      /       \
   BD     J      N     R        X
 / | \   / \    / \   / \      / \
A  C  F  I K    M  O  Q  S    T   Z
```

Will this be the final tree after Deleting Y... i am not sure thats why posting here to be corrected..thankss

Comment: How can T be on the right sub-tree of W?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's correct, T cannot be in the right sub-tree of W since T comes before W.

```
                 [P]
               /      \
              /        \
             /          \
            /            \
           /              \     
        [G][L]            [T]
       /  |   \          /   \
      /   |    \        /     \
     /    |     \      /       \
   BD     J      N     R        X
 / | \   / \    / \   / \      / \
A  C  F  I K    M  O  Q  S    W   Z
```

Here are the steps:

Remove Y:

```
                 [P]
               /      \
              /        \
             /          \
            /            \
           /              \     
        [G][L]            [W]
       /  |   \          /   \
      /   |    \        /     \
     /    |     \      /       \
   BD     J      N     R       null
 / | \   / \    / \   / \      / \
A  C  F  I K    M  O  Q  ST   X   Z
```

Replace with smallest from right sub-tree (Z), rebalance at Z's old location

```
                 [P]
               /      \
              /        \
             /          \
            /            \
           /              \     
        [G][L]            [W]
       /  |   \          /   \
      /   |    \        /     \
     /    |     \      /       \
   BD     J      N     R        Z
 / | \   / \    / \   / \      /
A  C  F  I K    M  O  Q  ST   X
```

Cannot borrow from sibling (X), merge children at Z:

```
                 [P]
               /      \
              /        \
             /          \
            /            \
           /              \     
        [G][L]            [W]
       /  |   \          /   \
      /   |    \        /     \
     /    |     \      /       \
   BD     J      N     R      [X,Z]
 / | \   / \    / \   / \  
A  C  F  I K    M  O  Q  ST
```

Cannot borrow from sibling (R), merge children at W:

```
                 [P]
               /      \
              /        \
             /          \
            /            \
           /              \     
        [G][L]      [Q,R,S,T,W,X,Z]
       /  |   \       
      /   |    \    
     /    |     \   
   BD     J      N  
 / | \   / \    / \  
A  C  F  I K    M  O
```

Merged node (previously W) is now too large, split evenly:

```
                 [P]
               /      \
              /        \
             /          \
            /            \
           /              \     
        [G][L]            [T]
       /  |   \          /   \
      /   |    \     [Q,R,S] [W,X,Z]
     /    |     \   
   BD     J      N  
 / | \   / \    / \  
A  C  F  I K    M  O
```

Left node of T is now too large, split evenly:

```
                 [P]
               /      \
              /        \
             /          \
            /            \
           /              \     
        [G][L]            [T]
       /  |   \          /   \
      /   |    \        / [W,X,Z]
     /    |     \      /
   BD     J      N     R
 / | \   / \    / \   / \
A  C  F  I K    M  O  Q  S
```

Right node of T is also too large, split evenly:

```
                 [P]
               /      \
              /        \
             /          \
            /            \
           /              \     
        [G][L]            [T]
       /  |   \          /   \
      /   |    \        /     \
     /    |     \      /       \
   BD     J      N     R        X
 / | \   / \    / \   / \      /  \
A  C  F  I K    M  O  Q  S    W    Z
```

Comment: which deletion case u applying here :S i am not getting this answer...i know now that T can not be in right Sub-tree W....

Answer (score 0):

it is so good question.
L goes to the root,
P goes to it's right child and sit near W 
N and it's children becomes left child of P
for delete Y, W must go middle down of R and Y
Y goes down between X and Z
now you can delete Y ...

```
            [   L  ]
            /      \
```

!!!!!!        /        \
              /          \
             /            \
            /              \
          [G]              [P]
          /  \            /   \
         /    \          /     \
        /      \        /       \
     [B D]     [J]     N       R  W
     / | \     / \    / \     /  |  \
    A  C  F   I   K  M   O   Q  ST  X Z --->Y

Answer (score 0):

it is so good question.
L goes to the root,
P goes to it's right child and sit near W 
N and it's children becomes left child of P
for delete Y, W must go middle down of R and Y
Y goes down between X and Z
now you can delete Y ...

```
            [   L  ]
            /      \
           /        \
          /          \
         /            \
        /              \     
      [G]              [P]
      /  \            /   \
     /    \          /     \
    /      \        /       \
 [B D]     [J]     N       R  W      
 / | \     / \    / \     /  |  \     
A  C  F   I   K  M   O   Q  ST  X Z --->Y
```